# Memory with non zero low index - any caveats?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vivado

In the VHDL language a common way to init a memory is:

```
type mem0_type (0 to MEM0_SIZE-1) of std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    signal mem0 : mem0_type;
```

For ease of use later in a memory and register adressnig table, I am **considering**:

```vhdl
type mem0_type (MEM0_ADDR to MEM0_ADDR+MEM0_SIZE-1) of std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    signal mem0 : mem0_type;
```

To be able to do something like this:

```vhdl
case switch is 
    when mem0'range => mem0(switch) <= data;
    when mem1'range => mem1(switch) <= data;
    when mem2'range => mem2(switch) <= data;
    when mem3'range => mem3(switch) <= data;
    when REG0_ADDR  => reg0 <= data;
    when REG1_ADDR  => reg1 <= data;
    when REG2_ADDR  => reg2 <= data;
    ...
end case;
```

Instead of something like:

```vhdl
case switch is 
    when MEM0ADDR to MEM0ADDR+MEM0_SIZE-1 => mem0(switch-MEM0ADDR) <= data;
    when MEM1ADDR to MEM1ADDR+MEM1_SIZE-1 => mem1(switch-MEM1ADDR) <= data;
    when MEM2ADDR to MEM2ADDR+MEM2_SIZE-1 => mem2(switch-MEM2ADDR) <= data;
    when REG0_ADDR  => reg0 <= data;
    when REG1_ADDR  => reg1 <= data;
    when REG2_ADDR  => reg2 <= data;
    ...
end case;
```

### Is there any downside of using a none zero index as the start adress if my synthesis tool allows it?

*Thank you for taking the time, I'd love to see more HDL activity on stack <3*

Comment: I'm sure your synthesiser will allow it. Either you'll get a memory with an unused portion (a waste of area), a memory whose lowest address isn't zero or a memory whose lowest address is zero with the memory shift being handled by the synthesiser (unlikely I think, but you might). Try it. But... You might find that different synthesisers do different things, which would make your code dependent on the synthesiser.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it would be better asked on the Electronics Stack Exchange site. This site is for programming. HDLs are already stretching that a bit, but questions like this that are not about VHDL language at all but are about synthesis I think are stretching to too far.

Comment: @Matthew Taylor Its always  hard with HDL to know where to post. All though stack has about 10x the VHDL posts of Stack Exchange EE. Are not compiler related questions ok on stack? I am quite new so just wondering :)

Comment: Well, I don't know. It's just my opinion. Notice that no one else (with sufficient power to vote) has agreed with me, so I wouldn't worry about it. You could ask on Meta, but (given this site is about programming) very few people on Meta will understand and your question will probably get a zillion downvotes and a closure within 3 femtoseconds.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor tend to disagree. People learn VHDL for a purpose and I'd strongly assume that - at least for most - this purpose is to get some logic going on their FPGAs. IMHO, if synthesis and even tool specific questions would be excluded from SO, not only tags like 'Vivado' and 'Quartus' would be mostly meaningless, but it would also defeat the purpose for most HDL learner's main interest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as suggested, but - since synthesis rules are not strictly standarised - I wouldn't bet on each and every synthesis tool to reliably detect and infer memory from your construct.

This appears to be a perfect use case for an alternative construct using an alias:

```
entity mem is
    generic
    (
        MEM_SIZE        : natural;
        DATA_WIDTH      : natural;
        START_ADDRESS   : unsigned(31 downto 0)
    );
    port
    (
        ...
    );
end entity mem;

architecture alias_architecture of mem is
    type mem_type is array (natural range <>) of std_ulogic_vector(DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
    signal mem : mem_type(0 to MEM_SIZE - 1);
    alias amem : mem_type(to_integer(START_ADDRESS) to to_integer(START_ADDRESS) + MEM_SIZE - 1) is mem;
begin
...
```

This way you still have the luxury of convenient addressing with the only place you need to deal with the offset is the alias definition. It probably does not guarantee every tool available will be able to guess what you meant but I'd assume it will at least increase the likelyhood.

[P.S.: tried that out of curiosity in Quartus II and unfortunately, it appears it can't be bothered to infer RAM blocks through the aliased array. YMMV with other synthesis tools.]